# Should I have a different crew for bombers than for fighters?

Tags: war-thunder

There are a few crew abilities that I want to upgrade.  They are called

Number of experienced gunners, Fire Accuracy, Fire Precision

These skills would only be good for bombers, right?  I'm guessing they would be useless for fighters because there is only one gunner in a fighter and it is not controlled by the AI.

Also, does this mean I should have one kind of crew for a fighter and another type for a bomber?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite right, on aircraft without gunners the number of experienced gunners along with their accuracy and precision are completely worthless.

It is more efficient to have a number of crew slots dedicated to bomber crews as these skills are expensive to upgrade and would be wasted on fighters.

Bear in mind though that some heavy fighters still have one or two gunners (the Beaufighter, for example) so plan accordingly. Spending some skill points on these gunners can turn the tide on pursuers.